# MySQL joining tables with origin info in result

Tags: php, mysql, loops, join

I have 2 tables with same fields

1. videos ( id, user_id, category_id, timestamp )
2. monthly_videos ( id, user_id, category_id, timestamp )

Now my question is can I join those two tables on a field user_id in a such way that I get "origin info" meaning information from which table result actually came ? I need to know when I loop through MySQL results with PHP like this:

```
forach($results as $result) {
    $entry_id = $result->id;
    // this id is from table videos or monthly_videos ???
    //if from table videos do something
    //if from table monthly_videos do something else
}
```

if that particular result is from table "videos" or table "monthly_videos".

Why I need this is because although id is auto-increment it is unique for that table only. User with id 5 can have entry with id 2 in table "videos" but he can also have entry id 2 in tables monthly_videos - and same goes for all fields (info can be duplicated). And it's OK actually I DON'T WANT TO REMOVE duplicated fields - I just need to know from which table it came ?

Only solution I have is to query each table separately and create a multidimensional array with all information and than loop through that array, but I was wondering if there is a way to do it with MySQL directly and just loop through results ?

Comment: As suggestion you could use one table for all your videos and denote their type (standard or monthly) with a `type_id` column or with a foreign key from another table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a UNION and a string value to mark the origin:

```
SELECT 'videos' As origin, id, user_id, category_id, timestamp FROM videos
UNION
SELECT 'monthly_videos', id, user_id, category_id, timestamp FROM monthly_videos
```

As Arth mentioned in his comment,

```
SELECT 'videos' As origin, id, user_id, category_id, timestamp FROM videos
UNION ALL
SELECT 'monthly_videos', id, user_id, category_id, timestamp FROM monthly_videos
```

could result in a better performance of the query while having the same result.

Comment: I'd probably use UNION ALL for this.. I know it makes no difference to the results, but the engine won't have to check for dupes so it should be faster.. also conceptually it makes more sense.